# Are there any TCP/IP stack implementations on top of Bluetooth for Java, more specificaly for Android?

Tags: java, android, http, bluetooth, tcp

What I need to do is pair with a Bluetooth enabled device which hosts some webservices and browse for DNS-SD services.

Then I have to pick one of those discovered services and make some http requests over https or other secure method.

I already did this trough WiFi, but for some reasons there's a need to do the same trough Bluetooth.

I did some research yesterday but I haven't found what I need. I'm not sure how to approach this.

Any input on this is welcomed.
Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the device hosting the services has bluetooth and wifi, but you can connect to it only through bluetooth? Will you do any development on the device hosting the services, or just on the client device, i.e. can you modify the server device in any way?

Comment: I can connect to the device either trough bluetooth or wifi. No, I won't be doing any development on the server device and I'm also assuming the device knows how to interpret the eventual requests trough bluetooth.

Answer (score 3):

Most implementations of bluetooth implement sockets on top of RFCOMM or L2CAP, but these are not standard sockets.

I've never used it, but I believe that the Bluetooth network encapsulation protocol (BNEP) allows for the use of standard TCP/IP networking over Bluetooth.  Android does not implement this and I don't think it is widely supported elsewhere.