# Reliable bluetooth on Android

Tags: android, tcp, bluetooth

I am looking for sending message over Bluetooth between Android devices. I followed the developer guide and it works. But while using it reveal that some sent messages can be lost.

I want to send reliable message like I could do in TCP over Wifi for example.
So far the answer I get is to implement myself an acknowledgement system in my application. But I believe there exist a simplest and better way to do like using TCP over Bluetooth. Looking around I found this disappointing answer :[Are there any TCP/IP stack implementations on top of Bluetooth for Java, more specificaly for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17856255/are-there-any-tcp-ip-stack-implementations-on-top-of-bluetooth-for-java-more-sp).

Is it really impossible to do so on Android ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do searching for various bluetooth protocols.
Bluetooth protocols are:

1. L2cap: unreliable
2. rfcomm: made on top of l2cap and reliable like tcp
3. obex: uses rfcomm as transport layer and used for sending objects.

So your choices may be rfcomm and obex protocols. Find methods to implement these on android. I implemented these in J2me not sure about android.

Comment: Ok thanks ! I will have a look on it (not now, I get busy by school). Keep in touch !

Answer (score 0):

I think you can "send releable message like I could do in tcp over wifi".  Bluetooth sockets is not the same as a regular TCP/IP stack, but I believe it is reliable.  I don't think you can lose a message without also experiencing an error (or exception) on your socket communication.

Are you saying that you've had messages disappear without an error when using Bluetooth sockets on Android?  Are you sure?

Comment: Recently I try again and yes, if you send let say 200 messages, you will lose some of them without warning (or maybe a hidden one I didn't catch?). But your messages arrive in the good order. Then if you wait a little bit (time for the buffer to get empty I guess) it works again.